# Is this the correct way to imitate the following POST request using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I need to imitate this request:

[image]

text part

```
POST /comeback_campaigns/entry HTTP/1.1
Host: ishin-global.aktsk.com
Accept: */*
X-Platform: android
X-Language: en
X-ClientVersion: 3.6.1
X-AssetVersion: 1510308536
X-DatabaseVersion: 1510542279
X-RequestVersion: 2
Content-Type: application/json
Authorization: MAC id="TVTYcxqDlO61l0yQYQnaKirWEVOPcVp2O4FCZOAb0pLrP++EEsKaqrlSho8VQRLFLV+4wvAV53DBwJyNuqUfqg==", nonce="1510773145:5a7b051af7f3e76e5b14f4e79753589f", ts="1510773145", mac="Eot1a1QPvyhecW3wNjWCW1JAENjuOjfjyxltmcguYqc="
Content-Length: 5
```

JSON part

```
null
```

I wrote it like this in my code, using the request function

```
url='http://ishin-global.aktsk.com/comeback_campaigns/entry'

myhead={'Accept':'*/*',
    'X-Platform':'android',
    'X-Language':'en',
    'X-ClientVersion':'3.6.1',
    'X-AssetVersion':'1510308536',
    'X-DatabaseVersion':'1510542279',
    'X-RequestVersion':'2',
    'Content-Type':'application/json',
    'Authorization':'MAC id='+mac_key +', nonce='+TS+':'+nonce+', ts='+ TS + ', mac='+mac_gen,
    'Content-Length':'5'
    }


payload='null'

r=requests.post(url, headers=myhead, json=payload)
```

Is this the correct way to do it? Do I have to send in the auth part like, `request.post(url, auth, header)`? Do I have to convert the access token in the image into an OAuth2 thing before using it?

Right now im getting an error saying

> oauth2_mac_rails/access_token_required

The access token is the MAC id right after authorization.

Comment: I suspect that sending `json='null'` might cause issues, either send an empty string or don't use this field.

Comment: Don't post screenshots of code or HTTP requests, when you can just copy and paste it in the question.

Comment: @alfasin I changed it to send json={}, but the error still remains that even though the authorization: contains the mac_ID(in this case its the access token), its still not receiving the access token though. 

i know its receiving the rest of the authorization fine, because if the mad ID at the end is wrong, it gives a different error

Comment: I have a feeling that `requests` will handle Content-Length for you, so you can probably remove that. Also, this request is weird in that it specifies `Content-Type: application/json`, but posts the literal string `null`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add quotes (`"`) around the individual parts of the `Authorization` key:

```
'Authorization': 'MAC id="' + mac_key + '", nonce="' + TS + ':' + nonce + '", ts="' + TS + '", mac="' + mac_gen + '"'
```

You are currently sending one long string without intermediate quotes:

```
'Authorization': 'MAC id=TVTxxx, nonce=151xxx:5a7xxx, ts=151xxx, mac=Eotxxx'
```

while your reference POST looks like:

```
'Authorization': 'MAC id="TVTxxx", nonce="151xxx:5a7xxx", ts="151xxx", mac="Eot..."'
```

Comment: hahaha thank you! it was the issue with the MAC id needing quotes around it. the rest of it didnt need it

Comment: If this was the right answer, feel free to accept it so that the question is marked as solved.

Comment: Have a look here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/374410 Additionally to accepting, you can vote (up/down) with the grey errors there.